# Protestant view on the canon

Tags: protestantism, early-church, canon, infallibility, protestant-bible

I am currently researching the Protestant view of the biblical canon and have encountered a variety of perspectives on the infallibility of the canon. For instance, the renowned Reformed theologian R.C. Sproul [argues](https://beggarsallreformation.blogspot.com/2011/02/sproul-bible-is-fallible-collection-of.html) that Scripture is a fallible collection of infallible books. This raises several questions: If the canon is not infallible, how can we be certain about the correct number of canonical books (e.g., 66, 73, or another number)? This ultimately leads to that canon is closed or not problem.

Others are those who argue that the canon is infallible, [as it was determined by the guidance of the Holy Spirit through the church fathers and councils](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/92956/58919) *(It is seems like saying they were infallible indirectly)*

**My question is how these views be reconciled with** ***sola scriptura*** **in protestant context**?

*Related : [Protestants on how the Biblical canon came?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92954/protestants-on-how-the-biblical-canon-came)*

Comment: There are three questions in the body of the above. There is no question in the header above. I am uncertain as to what is being asked.

Comment: I think it's probably a good question in there.  Maybe you could just ask which protestants belief in a open canon?

Comment: More clarified.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [How do Sola Scriptura defenders have a list of "scripture" since the list isn't mentioned in scripture?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89229/6071)